# Can we use same AWS IOT device certificate for two AWS regions?

Tags: aws-iot, aws-iot-core, amazon-device-messaging

I have tried to **use same AWS IOT  certificate  in two AWS Regions** (Stockholm & London).But device could connect **only** to the region which the certificate has created (Stockholm).

Can we use the same AWS IOT  device certificate for two AWS regions (belongs to single account)?

Steps :

- Create a IOT device certificate in **Stockholm** region
- Download  certificate (in Stockholm region )
- Import the downloaded certificate to **London** region

[This Old thread(2016)](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=224361) says that transferring  certificate to different region not allowed.But not sure are there any way to do that now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the CA of the certificate is registered in the specific region. The [documentation (section "Using X.509 client certificates in multiple AWS accounts with multi-account registration")](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/x509-client-certs.html) indicates that you should not register the CA if you want to use the same certificate in different accounts/regions.

> To use multi-account registration
>
> - Do not register the CA that signed the device certificates with AWS IoT.
> - Register the device certificates without a CA. See Register a client certificate without a registered CA (CLI).
> - Use the correct host_name in the SNI extension to TLS when the device connects to AWS IoT. See Transport security in AWS IoT.

Comment: @linuxbasis We have not registered our custom CA in aws. We are using AWS iot generated certificates. So CA is aws.

Comment: And we are not using multi accounts. We are using a single account. We need to use different regions in a single account.